# Read orc file in node js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orc

We're in the migration process and the new code base is developed in node js, the old one being in python. To read orc file from azure datalake we used pyorc for the python project, I was looking for something similar for node js project, basically for typescript or javascript files.
I could not find anything stable for the same, so posting the question here for help.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@npilots/norc (I haven't tried it)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have looked into the same, but it doesn't look stable, also there has been no update on the same from the last 4years. The git hub page says 'This project is in early stages of development'.